# How to declare this function correctly?

Tags: plugins, functions

Need to write this as functions to create a plugin and use an action hook to the plug-in in template page.

```
function my_frontend_custom_post( $new_post ) {

  <?php if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['new_post_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['new_post_nonce_field'], 'new_post_nonce_action' ) ) {

    if ( trim( $_POST['post-title'] ) === '' ) {
        $postingError .= 'Please insert a title. ';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $postTitle = trim( $_POST['post-title'] );
    }

    $new_post = array( array(
        'post_content'  =>  $_POST['post-content'],
        'post_title'    =>  wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post-title'] ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'cpt',
    );  

    if ( !$hasError == true ) {     

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $_POST['post-categ'], 'categories' );

        if ( $post_id ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
            echo 'Succes';
            exit;
        } // end - check if post's created and redirect to home_url
    } //end - if free of error insert_post and set_object categories

  } // end - first if wrapper
} // end - function
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_frontend_custom_post', 10, 1 );
```

Display the form:

```
function display_frontend_form() {

    <form id="new_post" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="post-title">The Title</label>
        <input id="post-title" name="post-title" type="text" />

        <label for="post-content">The Content</label>
        <textarea id="post-content" name="post-content"></textarea>

        <label for="post-categ">The Categories</label>
        <input id="post-categ" name="post-categ" type="text" />

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_post_nonce_action', 'new_post_nonce_field' ); ?>

        <button type="submit">Publish</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

    </form>

}
add_action( 'show_form', 'display_frontend_form' );
```

Then in the template page use an action hook to make the magic happen:

```
do_action( 'show_form'  );
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have? Or do you just need a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Trying to get a form for front-end posting. Then realized is better to create a plugin. I'm not sure how to declare it the right way. So a code review would be fine.

Comment: I'm also trying to get this to work: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238915/assign-category-to-front-end-post so i'm thinking of adding it with wp_insert_post_data filter, but im not sure where and how to use it.

Comment: This is not enough code for a review, which also would be off-topic here and on-topic on the other site, see my link.

Comment: There is no question I can find here. Please edit this to have an actual amswerable code related question with the full context.

Comment: This is not working, so the Question would be, How to fix it so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't see `$args` assigned anywhere.
Secondly before displaying in front-end, check if post is created with your values.

Little debugging like printing `$new_post` before insert might give you your issue.

Comment: Hi, I just added the full code. So its easier to know whats going on. Thanks

Comment: The posting works when in the template page, but when I create a Plug-in it does not work.

Comment: If this works in functions.php and not in plugin, your plugin might not be initiated properly.
Just a note, if you are using `class` in you plugin `add_action` will need class name to be specified. I always forget to do that in my plugins